# Linux - keep USB HDD alive programatically (no spin down)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, sleep

I have faulty HDD attached to 24/7 server, which sometimes throws I/O error after spin up. Thus I want to prevent it from spinning down programatically. It's about 6 years old Samsung G3 Station. No critical data on it, however I/O errors paralyze some file servers running on machine until I manually remount drive so It's inconvenient.

`hdparm -S 0` doesn't work. `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/null` of 100mb every 10 min triggers caching (I don't really want to read ~16 gb of data every 10 min just to bypass caching).

Comment: Now this may sound insolent, but I don't think you're approaching this the right way. Having a 24/7 service running on an already faulting disk drive would call for a replacement instead of taxing the faulty drive even more by not letting it spin down ever.

Comment: If I'll replace it i'll have to use USB drive anyways. They typically have issues with continuos spinup / spindown thus may die quickly. I'm looking for way of dealing with power saving behavior of USB drives because I've already run out of SATA ports. Even if it wouldn't be faulty I don't like 3 seconds lag before access and annoying sound of spinup.

Comment: Have you checked the disk SMART status? It may be at the point of failing completely.

Comment: It's "failing" for like 2 years already or more. It's me who is finally at the point of getting mad at necessity of remounting drive once a week on average :P Also no data corruption at all (btrfs csum monitoring) so welp. I'm gonna use it till complete death. As i said data is secure so I don't really care about this particular drive but about USB drives behavior in general. I have also non-faulty (yet) 5TB WD MyBook which also spins down and up every 10 min but I'm afraid it may quickly become faulty after like 5000 spinups every week...

Comment: Have you tried `touch`?

Comment: what about `hdparm -B 254`?

Comment: @TomYan well `hdparm -Y /dev/sdb` stopped working after `hdparm -B 254` also hdd didn't spin down for like 20 min already, so I think it actually works, thanks.